# Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer in PHP: align a single cell

Tags: php, pear, spreadsheet-excel-writer

I am currently working with the Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer in PHP.
It works fine with the data I have.
But now I want to format my data.

Let's say I have 3 columns: Position, Article and Price.
The Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer writes each line correctly.
But now I want to format it that the data in the Price-columns is right-aligned, while the other two values in each line shall be left-aligned.

When I use `->setAlign("left");`
it alignes the whole row to the left.
But I want ONE SINGLE VALUE to be aligned right.
How do I do that?
If I write `->setAlign("right");` it aligns all values in that row to the right.

Here is the example:

```
$worksheet->writeString($row_pos, $col, $item[$val], $format_pos_data);
```

As long as I am in the same row, the ->align()-value affects the whole row.
Is there a way I can change that behaviour?

Comment: What's the value of your $format_pos_data variable?

Comment: The value was: 
`
$format_pos_data =& $this->workbook->addFormat();
$format_pos_data->setAlign("left");
`

But I found out how to fix the problem.
I have to take two different variables.
One like the above and one with `->setAlign('right')`.

If I use two different variables, it works:

`
if(strtoupper($val) == "PRICE"){
      $worksheet->writeString($row_pos, $col, $item[$val], $format_pos_data_right);
     } else {
      $worksheet->writeString($row_pos, $col, $item[$val], $format_pos_data_left);
     }`

Comment: Good for you :) Add that as answer and mark it as correct so other users can see it if they come across the same problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that.
Sorry I didn't do that earlier...I am new to stackoverflow, I have to learn how to deal with things here ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to fix the problem. I have to take two different variables. One like the above and one with ->setAlign('right'). If I use two different variables, it works:

```
if (strtoupper($val) == "PRICE") {
    $worksheet->writeString($row_pos, $col, $item[$val], $format_pos_data_right);
} else {
    $worksheet->writeString($row_pos, $col, $item[$val], $format_pos_data_left);
}
```